# Why resources on collection has different routing helper then regular post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes.rb I had this resource

```
resources :home_screen_buttons do
    post :update_multiple, :on => :collection
end
```

**update_multiple** helper is **update_multiple_home_screen_buttons**

Then I decided to remove resource because i need only **update_multiple** method in my controller, so I changed routes.rb to

```
post "home_screen_buttons/update_multiple"
```

It create helper **home_screen_buttons_update_multiple** instead of **update_multiple_home_screen_buttons**

Why it has different routing helper name?

It makes sense that :on => :collection has different helper then :on => :member, but is there any other way then adding :as => :update_multiple_home_screen_buttons to my post method for same behavior?

Comment: Covered the latter concern in answer below too. Use RESTful actions wherever they convey the meaning with respect to that resource. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Rails does this. When `match` is used, it maps the URI to the action and creates the corresponding helper path as controller_action_path
but when it is used as collection, that becomes RESTful action for that resource and Rails gives it a logical name relating to a collection. As quoted as an example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

generates `search_photos_path`.

You could have done this:

```
resources :home_screen_buttons, :only => [:update_multiple] do
    post :update_multiple, :on => :collection
end
```